# converting json object in to another object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data array like bellow:

```
[
    [7.54629420634032, 80.49201965332031],
    [7.532680021759206, 80.50506591796875],
    [7.517023180703112, 80.50506591796875]
]
```

I want to create this in to a object in JavaScript. but when i do that it shows bellow:

```
Object {
    0: "[", 
    1: "[", 
    2: "7", 
    3: ".", 
    4: "5", 
    5: "4", 
    6: "6", 
    7: "2", 
    8: "9", 
    9: "4", 
    10: "2",
    …
 }
```

But I want to create the object same as first on 
looks like below:

```
[
    [7.54629420634032, 80.49201965332031],
    [7.532680021759206, 80.50506591796875],
    [7.517023180703112, 80.50506591796875]
]
```

Please help me to do this?
Best regards.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What do you want your object to look like?

Comment: same as the question    `[
    [7.54629420634032, 80.49201965332031],
    [7.532680021759206, 80.50506591796875],
    [7.517023180703112, 80.50506591796875]
]`

Comment: Nope, still not clear. You want to create an array of arrays that is exactly the same as your original array of arrays?

Comment: So you don't want to create an object at all. Are you asking "how do I clone this array of arrays?"

Comment: yes thats i wan to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinarily you would be able to use `var arr2 = arr.slice(0)` but only if this was a non-nested array.

I would be inclined in this case to stringify to JSON and then re-parse the array:

```
var arr2 =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ds0hzsmc/)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the JSON string of the array, and then split it for each character:

```
var myArray = [[7.54629420634032, 80.49201965332031],[7.532680021759206, 80.50506591796875],[7.517023180703112, 80.50506591796875]];
var splitObject = JSON.stringify(myArray).split('');
```

This will return an array contaning each character in the stringified representation.

---

`myArray` just defines your array from the question. Then it gets stringified (the JSON representation). That string is then split into an array, with each character given its own item. That is saved as `splitObject`.

Comment: can you tell me it step by step

Comment: ok i understand it than what i do? thanks for supporting me.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with it once you have that array of characters.

Comment: yes like this `["[", "[", "7", ".", "5", "4", "6", "2", "9", "4", "2", "0", "6", "3", "4", "0", "3", "2", ",", "8", "0", ".", "4",…]`

Comment: Yes - that is what `splitObject` is. It's up to you to do something with it now.

Comment: this is my previous post it has this error. first i can't found it. but after few hours find the error where it come. please if there is a any solution tell me. best regards.  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26988480/cannot-draw-polygon-path-with-php-and-mysql[link]